# Nested Set Analysis in QlikSense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, sense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

My User_ID has several images and with this piece of code I receive the largest IMAGE_NR .

```
  max({$<USER_ID = {'8638087'}> } IMAGE_NR)
```

Every image number is linked to an IMAGE_ID. How do I get this?

In words:

> Give me IMAGE_ID where IMAGE_NR = largest IMAGE_NR of my USER_ID

I tried following that doesn't work:

```
  sum({$<max({<USER_ID={'8638087'}> } IMAGE_NR)>} IMAGE_ID)
```

Thank you for any thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step solution.

You mention that this already brings back the correct IMAGE_NR:

```
max({$<USER_ID = {'8638087'}> } IMAGE_NR)
```

Now you want the IMAGE_ID. The logic is:

```
=only({CORRECT_IMAGE_NR_SET_ANALYSIS} IMAGE_ID)
```

I generally prefer to avoid search mode (double quotes inside element list) and instead use a higher evaluation level on the top calculation, so I would recommend:

```
$(=
    'only({<IMAGE_NR={'
    & max({$<USER_ID = {'8638087'}> } IMAGE_NR)
    & '}>} IMAGE_ID)'
)
```

This would also provide you a nice preview formula in the formula editor, something like:

```
only({<IMAGE_NR={210391287}>} IMAGE_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but i believe it's something like :

```
only({<IMAGE_NR={'$(=max(IMAGE_NR))'}, USER_ID={'8638087'}>} IMAGE_ID)
```

Comment: Should work, think all you need extra is the USER_ID set in the max() otherwise the max IMAGE_NR might be out of range for the selected USER_ID. only({<IMAGE_NR={'$(=max({<USER_ID={'8638087'}>} IMAGE_NR))'}, USER_ID={'8638087'}>} IMAGE_ID)

Answer (score 1):

If the dimension of the table is USER_ID then this will return the IMAGE_ID of the maximum IMAGE_NR per USER_ID. Should work / return results for any dimension, but then will have to be read as maximum IMAGE_NR per whatever that dimesion is. The minus on IMAGE_NR is to get the largest/last sorted value

```
firstsortedvalue(IMAGE_ID,-IMAGE_NR)
```

If you're using it in a text box with no dimension then you can also add the set analysis

```
firstsortedvalue({<USER_ID={'8638087'}>} IMAGE_ID,-IMAGE_NR)
```